# How do I configure logging for ulimits?

Tags: linux, logs, centos, ulimit

I was wondering if anything gets logged when any [ulimits](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html) are hit (open files, etc). If so, where is this logged, and what should I be looking for? I'm using CentOS 6.

Comment: For what operating system, exactly?  If something like this exists, it's probably OS specific.

Comment: Those ulimits make some syscalls fail if their limits are reached, nothing more. Unless there's some auditing framework for this ([audit](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) perhaps?), you would probably have to monitor the applications with something like [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/), etc.

Comment: The limits are always exist, even if not set. An application is able and can handle them. As @CristianCiupitu stated, you can monitor every failed system call with auditd.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**audit**](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to log the failures of the corresponding system calls (syscalls), although not every excess manifests this way. For example as 
[Henk Langeveld](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139030/1174) pointed out, exceeding `RLIMIT_RTTIME` causes the kernel to send a signal.

Let's take for example the [`RLIMIT_NOFILE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) limit:

> Specifies a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number that
>   can be opened by this process.  Attempts ([`open`(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), `pipe`(2), `dup`(2),
>   etc.) to exceed this limit yield the error `EMFILE`.  (Historically, this
>   limit was named `RLIMIT_OFILE` on BSD.)

So you'll have to monitor for example the `open` syscall. Its [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> `open()`, `openat()`, and `creat()` return the new file descriptor, or -1 if
>   an error occurred (in which case, [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is set appropriately).
>
> ERRORS
>
> `open()`, `openat()`, and `creat()` can fail with the following errors:
>
> `EMFILE` - The process already has the maximum number of files open.

This means you have to audit the `open` syscalls that fail with `EMFILE`. The man page suggests that `open` returns -1 and sets `errno` to `EMFILE`, but what happens actually is that the `open` **syscall** returns `-EMFILE` and [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h;h=2b9ea85d8e9c91c4d8d414a98cc40b82d261153c;hb=6164128f1ca84eea240b66f977054e16b94b3c86#l225) *converts* it into -1 and sets `errno` to `EMFILE` <sup>*</sup>.

Now that we have straighten that out, let's add an audit rule:

```
[root@h ~]# auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=`uname -m` -S open \
                                    -F uid=ciupicri -F exit=-EMFILE -k "UL-SE"
```

Let's test the limits:

```
[ciupicri@h ~]$ ulimit -n 10
[ciupicri@h ~]$ python -c 'from __future__ import print_function; f = [(print(i), open("/etc/passwd")) for i in range(10)]'
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/etc/passwd'
```

And check the logs:

```
[root@h ~]# ausearch --start recent -k UL-SE
...
time->Wed Jun 25 21:27:37 2014
type=PATH msg=audit(1403720857.418:63): item=0 name="/etc/passwd" nametype=UNK
NOWN
type=CWD msg=audit(1403720857.418:63):  cwd="/home/ciupicri"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1403720857.418:63): arch=40000003 syscall=5 success=no 
exit=-24 a0=8ed72e0 a1=8000 a2=1b6 a3=8f24d11 items=1 ppid=1110 pid=1139 auid=
5000 uid=5000 gid=5000 euid=5000 suid=5000 fsuid=5000 egid=5000 sgid=5000 fsgi
d=5000 tty=pts3 ses=2 comm="python" exe="/usr/bin/python" subj=unconfined_u:un
confined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="UL-SE"
...
```

The "Security Guide" for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 has a ["System Auditing"](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) chapter where you can read more on the subject.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Thanks go to [fche](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/48085/fche) for pointing this out.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect kernel source for this.

#### Example:

The CPU Timers in the linux kernel
([posix-cpu-timers.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/posix-cpu-timers.c#L866)) will just send a SIGKILL to the offending process when the hard limit is reached.  The soft limit triggers an SIGXCPU once a second, and a Watchdog message.

You can search for the other limits and/or signals for more detail.

Comment: With thanks to the Linux Cross Reference project