# ulimit logging?

Tags: logs, ulimit

When a user/process hits a `ulimit` is there a way to log this at the system level? I cannot find any logging information in `/var/log/messages`, or `dmesg`. I did some preliminary research and the answer is that the application has to 'detect' this; is there a way to just globally log when these limits are reached?

Comment: Have you seen [the answer to this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139011/how-do-i-configure-logging-for-ulimits)?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/PaulDaviesC/Logging-limits.conf

The above is an attempt to monitor failed syscalls with auditd and then determine when/if that was due to ulimit - I think that's as close as you can get without modifying the kernel and/or PAM to directly dump such events to log.

Comment: do the auditd rules persist between reboot, or do they need to be run every time